# Context showing null pointer Exception in Custom Adapter class?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a ListView with a custom adapter.
In the customer adapter class, I'm passing a Context object to its super class and also passing a Context object to the `MainActivity` while creating the object for the Adapter class.

It shows the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mylistpractice/com.mylistpractice.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Now I pass `getApplicationContext()` rather than the `Context` object while passing the argument from `MainActivity` and it doesn't show any error.

I am confused about the difference between passing a Context object and passing `getApplicationContext()`.

But it's not showing any data in the ListView.

This is the Adapter class

```
public class Myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {
ArrayList<Data> arraydata;
Context context;

public Myadapter(ArrayList<Data> arraydata,Context context) {
    super(context,R.layout.content,arraydata);
    this.arraydata=arraydata;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Data data=getItem(position);
    Viewholder viewholder;
    View vi=convertView;

    if(vi==null) {
        viewholder=new Viewholder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, parent, false);
        viewholder.name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewholder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.id);
        vi.setTag(viewholder);
    } else {
        viewholder=(Viewholder)vi.getTag();
    }
     viewholder.name.setText(data.getName());
     viewholder.id.setText(data.getId());
     return vi;
}

public class Viewholder {
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
}
}
```

this is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Data> arraydata=new ArrayList<>();
    Myadapter myadapter;
    Context context;
    Data data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        setList();
        myadapter = new Myadapter(arraydata,MainActivity.this);
        list.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }

    public void setList() {

        for(int i=0;i<15;i++) { 
             String s,id;
             data = new Data();
             data.setName("Farhana:::"+i);
             s = data.getName();
             data.setId("Id:::"+i);
             id = data.getId();
             arraydata.add(data);
             Log.e("DAtA:--",s);
             Log.e("ID:--",id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: return arraydata size in getCount method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but not showing anydata in listview

Because you told it not to create any views.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

You are using an ArrayAdapter. You don't need to implement `getCount`, but if you do, return the size of the list

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arraydata == null ? 0 : arraydata.size();
}
```

---

Anyways, regarding your question, tend to use `MainActivity.this` like you have done for the Context (Activities are Contexts).

If your error is here

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

Then, that could instead be

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
```

which you got the context from the constructor

Comment: You misunderstood my point. It is returning zero. Therefore nothing is displaying

Answer (score 1):

you are overriding method getCount(); and it is returning zero, you have to return the size of the array-list.